# Selenium: Get children with a specific class

Tags: python, selenium

Given a child element `e`, is there a good (or pythonic) way to find all children with tag `div` and a class `cls`? I've tried `e.find_element_by_xpath('div[starts-with(@class, "cls")]')` but that doesn't seem to search within `e`. It seems to return the first match in the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below

```
children = e.find_elements_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "cls")]')
```

Note that you need to start your XPath with `./` that means *direct child of current node (`e`)*

If elements are dynamically generated by JavaScript, try to wait for them to appear in DOM:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

children = wait(e, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "cls")]')))
```

Comment: Strange that it can't find the `div` element when it's clearly in the HTML when I print the `innerHTML` attribute. I've tried `starts-with` and `contains`.

Comment: @JohnM. , maybe you need *descendants*, but not *children*. In this case you might need `'.//div[contains(@class, "cls")]'` (extra slash). Also required elements might be generated dynamically , so you need to wait some time until they rendered on page